# Problems resizing UICollectionView

Tags: ios, xamarin, uicollectionview

I have two UICollectionViews on the screen. After onClick event I want to resize one of them.

My problem is that the UICollectionVies doesn't change its size, it is moving to other screen position.

The original frame size is:

```
(0, 0, 1024, 588)
```

I have tried with this:

```
collectionView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0 , 1024 , 768);
```

and this:

```
this.viewer.Bounds= new CGRect(0, 0 , 1024 , 768);
```

But nothing works.

I also followed this link [Resize UICollectionView Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017528/resize-uicollectionview-height) but doesn't works for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you use autolayout?

Comment: No, the autolayout is disabled.

Comment: Ideally, it should be resizing since UICollectionView is a UIView. Please post more code.